# How can I get postgres JDBC working in Scala Mac OS?

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, jdbc

I'm trying to do a tutorial to connect to Postgres from scala, using the JDBC drivers

https://mackler.org/LearningSlick2/

However, i'm getting this error message:

```
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>  import org.postgres
<console>:7: error: object postgres is not a member of package org
        import org.postgres
```

I'm using MacOSX with postgress installed via http://postgresapp.com/

What am I missing to properly use the jdbc connection?

Comment: You should really start using a build system, like sbt. It'll help you better in the long run.

Comment: thanks, figured out how to do that (though had you explained in an answer, I would have accepted it as it'd have been more helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your postgres jars are not on your class path. Try:

```
$ scala -classpath postgres.jar
```

Where `postgres.jar` is hypothetical example.

You may need to add all jars using something like `pathToPostGresLib/*.jar` while starting your REPL session.